# Bash script to replace a file if it has a particular string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of files that I want to check for a particular string. If the string exists in the file, I want to replace it with a new version that I have. What is the easiest way of going about this?

Answer (score 4):

```
for file in "`grep -l "foo" bar gazi`"; do cp -p --backup=numbered replace "$file"; done
```

where *replace* is the path to the replacement file, *bar* and *gazi* represent a list of files to be checked, and *foo* is the search string of interest.

If you require additional assistance formulating an appropriate regular expression for grep (above) please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: +1. But you might want to add "cp $file /tmp/$file.backup" first, just in case things go terribly wrong.

Comment: A very valid point, although this can be streamlined using the --backup operator for cp: `cp -p --backup=numbered replace $file` which will append ~n~ to a copy of the original $file if it exists before replacing it.

Comment: Note that without quotes around the "$file", it will fail for files that have spaces in them.

Comment: The shell will tokenize the output of the grep on whitespace, so $file will never have a space in it anyway.  If grep returns a filename with spaces in it, it will split the parts and set them to file individually.

Comment: Corrected by quoting the backticks which preserves the spacing. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

grep can search a file for a string and will return 0 if it finds it, you could use this as part of a conditional to replace the file, something like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ !`/bin/grep -q teststring /path/to/file` ]; then
    cp newfile oldfile
 fi
```

Comment: The brackets and backticks aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a file with the list of files in it?  I don't know if you've got a static file you're replacing matching files with, or a potential replacement per file.  This handles the second case, for the first, merely replace $i.new with the static file name.

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/listoffiles` ; do
    if grep string $i > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        cp $i $i.old
        cp $i.new $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1. And I'd give an extra +1 if I could for the backup to .old, just in case things go badly.

Comment: Note that without quotes around the "$i" this will fail on files that have spaces in it.

Comment: Actually, quotes around $i won't protect you in that case since the shell will split the output of `cat /var/tmp/listoffiles` on spaces.  If you have spaces in the names of the files, you have to do things differently...perhaps with a shell function and xargs?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with all of the grep tests, sed can do this without a test really.

sed -i.BACKUP 's/STRING YOU WANT TO REPLACE/NEW STRING/' file

If the string isn't there, it won't do anything. Just worth mentioning. From your question I wasn't sure if you were trying to replace the whole file or just a string within it.

Comment: I believe he is trying to replace the whole file, not just the string.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to process files in a loop in a shell script is to pipe the command into `while` or redirect a file into the `done` statement of a `while` loop. This will handle any name except those that contain newlines. You should not use the form `for f in $(cmd)`.

In this example, `find` is the command that produces the list of files:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | while read -r filename
do
    if grep -qs "$string" "$filename"  # or use >/dev/null 2>&1 instead of -qs
    then
        cp "$replacement" "$filename"
    fi
done
```

or, here the list is contained in a file:

```
while read -r filename
...
done < "$file_with_list"
```

Another method is to use `xargs`.

For a command that produces the list of files (e.g. `find`):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -I % env string=$string sh 'grep -qs "$string" "%" && cp replacement_file "%"'
```

The preceding method will work in cases where filenames may include newlines.

If the list is in a file:

```
xargs -a "$file_with_list" -I % env string=$string sh 'grep -qs "$string" "%" && cp replacement "%"'
```

All of these examples will work in cases where filenames may include spaces.